# MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://? in python

Tags: python

```
  if not scheme:
     error = ("Invalid URL {0!r}: No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://{0}?")
     error = error.format(to_native_string(url, 'utf8'))

     raise MissingSchema(error)

  if not host:
     raise InvalidURL("Invalid URL %r: No host supplied" % url)
```

while running this code, Getting an error like

```
MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?
```

Comment: The URL is clearly an empty string therefore it definitely does not have a scheme

Comment: It is very obvious why this error is raised, because you posted the trivial code for doing just that. So, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You are raising your own error. `scheme` is returning `False`, so the code raises the custom error your wrote within the first 4 lines of code. We cannot see what `scheme` is defined as so it will be hard to give an exact answer.